# Por que en la page de github no me salen los estilos CSS y el Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

hice un Cifrador Cesar para practicar un poco de HTML, CSS y JS y lo subi a mi repositorio de github, mi idea era que se puediera ver con la github page pero no me toma ni los estilos ni el JS, si alquien me puede dar una mano lo agradeceria.

este es el repositorio: https://github.com/vvazquez86/cifradorcesar

esta seria la github page: https://vvazquez86.github.io/cifradorcesar/

desde ya gracias!

Comment: La ruta de los estilos css es incorrecta, si revisas consola te devuelve un 404, revisa las rutas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para referencia futura, si el archivo html está en el mismo directorio que otra carpeta o archivo, no es necesario que incluya una barra inclinada al principio de los atributos src o href. Además, si necesita acceder a los archivos de uno, dos o muchos directorios, puede usar dos puntos "../../" como sustituto.

Modifica:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/estilos.css">
```

por

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
```

y

```
<script src="/main.js" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

por

```
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! funciono